# Get ID from Listbox-Item after click on Button in Powershell

Tags: powershell, button, listbox

i generate a Listbox to show all current remote sessions (user) on a server

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -credential CREDS -scriptBlock {query.exe user | sort-object }  | %{ [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_) }
```

I will use this snippet for my button

```
$Button= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,470)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$Button.ForeColor ="red"
$Button.Text = "KILL"
$form.Controls.Add($Button)
```

Finally i want choose an item of my listbox and get the session id of selected user, after i clicked on the button.

At the end, the user should log out with a click on the button

```
$Button.Add_Click({ logoff SESSION_OF_MY_LISTED/SELECTED_USER }) ;
```

How i get the id from the listed (selected user) after i click on the button?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT (complete listbox snippet):

```
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,60) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(272,20) 
$listBox.Height = 400

Invoke-Command -ComputerName COMPUTER -credential CREDS -scriptBlock {query.exe user | sort-object }  | %{ [void] $listBox.Items.Add($_) }

$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
```

[bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Zj5.png)

Comment: What does your ListBox code look like and how are you adding your `Invoke-Command` to it?

Comment: Hi,

see EDIT at first posting

Thanks

Comment: also the output are bad formated, how can i only display "Username" and "State" ?

Comment: While there are ways to make this work, it can get unreliable since you are dealing with complete strings that somehow looks like a table. I think it would do you good if you convert it to a PowerShell object. I recommend this to do that. That will fix ur output formatting as well as make it easier to pick the user's ID to logoff. https://www.itdroplets.com/get-list-users-logged-list-servers-powershell/

Comment: hi, i found also the site, but in my test environment this snippets not work? can you explain me how i can change my snippets that it will work? i have to add the admincred for the remote computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement that for example this way. I write here only relevant parts. I do not have server to connect to and I only have one user on my computer, but it works for this one user. Maybe there will be some tweaks needed.

```bsh
# Simple class for using as item for listbox.
class LbItem
{
    LbItem($data)
    {
        # According to your image of bad data, you have different culture,
        # and so different "column names". So you need to change those names here
        # when accessing the elements of $data. My column names in query.exe are:
        #   - USERNAME
        #   - SESSIONNAME
        #   - ID
        #   - STATE
        #   - IDLE TIME
        #   - LOGON TIME

        $this.Id = [System.Convert]::ToInt32($data.ID)
        # It seems, current user has ">" prepended in name, so remove it.
        $this.UserName = $data.USERNAME.TrimStart(">")
        $this.SessionName = $data.SESSIONNAME
        $this.State = $data.STATE
        $this.IdleTime = $data.{IDLE TIME}
        $this.LogonTime = $data.{LOGON TIME}
    }

    [int] $Id
    [string] $UserName
    [string] $SessionName
    [string] $State
    [string] $IdleTime
    [string] $LogonTime

    # This is diplayed in the listbox, so change it for your needs.
    [string] ToString()
    {
        return $this.UserName
    }
}

# Simplified version of your command, because I do not connect to other server,
# but I work only on my own computer.
$data = (query.exe user | Sort-Object) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Fill the listbox with custom classes.
foreach ($dataItem in $data) 
{
    [void] $listBox.Items.Add([LbItem]::new($dataItem))
}

# You can access the Id of current item and use it.
$id = $listBox.SelectedItem.Id
```